# static keyword and block in java

Tags: java, static

I saw the below code in one example, I unable to understand that what they doing and what they representing from same code

what is the meaning for below code in java

```
static 
{
    variable 1;
    variable 2;
    variable 3;
    variable 4;
}
```

Comment: `Static` should be `static` beginning with a small case letter.

Comment: These are called Static bolks

Comment: So many duplicates available. Check on right side of `Stackoverflow` in the `Related` part.

Comment: when asking for what this is - how should one find the duplicates..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a static block.

```
static{
  System.out.print("Hello");
}
```

**Property of static block: It executes before the execution of first static method.**

Answer (score 1):

Static blocks in Java

Unlike C++, Java supports a special block, called static block (also called static clause) which can be used for static initializations of a class. This code inside static block is executed only once: the first time you make an object of that class or the first time you access a static member of that class (even if you never make an object of that class). For example, check output of following Java program.
// filename: Main.java
class Test {
    static int i;
    int j;

```
// start of static block
static {
    i = 10;
    System.out.println("static block called ");
}
// end of static block
```

}

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

```
    // Although we don't have an object of Test, static block is
    // called because i is being accessed in following statement.
    System.out.println(Test.i);
}
```

}

Output:
static block called
10

Also, static blocks are executed before constructors. For example, check output of following Java program.
// filename: Main.java
class Test {
    static int i;
    int j;
    static {
        i = 10;
        System.out.println("static block called ");
    }
    Test(){
        System.out.println("Constructor called");
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

```
   // Although we have two objects, static block is executed only once.
   Test t1 = new Test();
   Test t2 = new Test();
}
```

}

```
Output:
static block called
Constructor called
Constructor called
```